# recursive bubble sort ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting, recursion

I am trying to build a recursive bubble sorting method in Ruby. It makes it through one pass fine, but it keeps returning after that. It seems that my 
`if array == swapped_array` is being triggered, but I don't understand where my `array` variable is being redefined.

```
def bubble_sort(array, swapped = true)
  return array if swapped == false
  i = 0
  if swapped == true
    swapped_array = comparator(array)
  end
  if array == swapped_array
    swapped = false
    bubble_sort(array, swapped)
  else bubble_sort(swapped_array)
  end
end

def comparator(array, i = 0)
  return array if i == array.length - 1
  if array[i] > array[i+1]
    array[i], array[i+1] = array[i+1], array[i]
  end
  i += 1
  comparator(array, i)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
swapped_array = comparator(array)
```

... takes the return value of `comparator` and assigns it to `swapped_array`. But `comparator` (eventually) returns the original argument `array`, which is the same `array` as the one defined in the caller. So

```
array == swapped_array
```

is always true.

If you want to compare two different arrays, you can call `.dup` on the array. This creates a new object with the same values as the original.

Answer (score 0):

It is because in `comparator`, you are swapping the elements in the original array. Whatever you do to it, `array` and `swapped_array` in `bubble_sort` refer to the same array instance, and hence will always be the same. To solve the problem, add a single line to the top of your definition:

```
def comparator(array, i = 0)
  array = array.dup
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked.

However, I'm still confused about how `array = array.dup` fixes it. If comparator is modifying the original array, why doesn't this make the original array also equivalent to `array.dup`, thereby giving me the same problem?

Comment: After doing this, your `array` will refer to a different instance (copy) of an array. You are doing operations like `array[...] = ...`, which will now modify the newly referred array, not the original one.